# pthread_mutex_errorcheck_np initialization error

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

Below code gives me compilation error:

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex= PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP;
int i=0;
void *func(void *a)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    i++;
    printf("The value of thread is: %d\n",i);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL); 
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t id1,id2;
    if(pthread_create(&id1,NULL,func,NULL)<0)
    perror("pthread_create error\n");
    pthread_join(id1,NULL);
    pthread_join(id2,NULL);

}
```

The error is:

```
 error: invalid initializer
 pthread_mutex_t mutex= PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP;
```

related content of my pthread.h is:

```
enum
{
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_TIMED_NP,
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP,
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP,
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP
#if defined __USE_UNIX98 || defined __USE_XOPEN2K8
  ,
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL = PTHREAD_MUTEX_TIMED_NP,
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE = PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP,
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK = PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP,
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT = PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL
#endif
#ifdef __USE_GNU
  /* For compatibility.  */
  , PTHREAD_MUTEX_FAST_NP = PTHREAD_MUTEX_TIMED_NP
#endif
};
```

Why this compilation error is occuring? I am not able to get any definite answer googling it.
I am using `gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)`

The command I used for compilation : `gcc prog.c -lpthread`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP` when initializing the mutex statically with '=' (note the extra `_INITIALIZER`). `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP` is for when you're initializing it at runtime using `pthread_mutex_init(3)`.

It is better to use `-pthread` than `-lpthread` by the way. It sets preprocessor flags to make some functions reentrant for example.

Comment: Getting error :‘PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP’ undeclared here (not in a function)

Comment: It seems you also need to add `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before including `<pthreads.h>` (and preferably before including any headers). It looks like `_NP` is for **n**on-**p**ortable, and you explicitly need to tell the implementation that you're okay with using them anyway.

Comment: Yes, this made it right. But how do I run it without making it NP. Is it possible that my compiler only supports NP variation?

Comment: Yup, it looks like the Linux glibc implementation (which uses NPTL -- Native POSIX Threads for Linux -- on modern systems) does not support `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK`. I haven't looked into what the non-portable parts are.